# What are the pros and cons of validating email address by code and by activation link. Django

Tags: python, django, validation, email, server

In Django, during site register, input to the EmailField is validated by `class EmailValidator:` [Link to the code.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d01709aae21de9cd2565b9c52f32732ea28a2d98/django/core/validators.py#L156)

However, this validation looks a little bit lengthy and source consuming to me. After so much checking it is still probable for a validated email address to **not** be in use.

Don't you think it would be much better if email-validation-by-code was totally skipped and authentication was dependent only on the activation link in terms of server resources and time. This would also provide more genuine signups/registers on the website.

Almost all webpages today send the user an activation link. It is almost inevitable for servers not to use computational power on sending emails anyway.

Is there anything that I miss about validating-by-code? Or are there any situations that activation link method would not work? What is the reason Django chose it that way? Thank you.

Comment: The email validator does not mean you can not send a confirmation link as well. Typically both are used. It only validates that you do not write (either by accident or on purpose `no.email`).

Comment: An activation link also does not solve all problems, since one can make use of a "throwaway email address".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes they don't restrict each other. I was asking to save resources. It is also true that a person can have a throwaway email but they need to spend more effort on that, which slows them down in the long term.

Comment: but in essence the `EmailValidator` works with a few regular expressions, that is not that computationally expensive.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You might have a point. SignUp is one time operation and having a little bit (which is relative btw) more computation at each signup would not make such a big difference. Still, compared to Django team, I would keep the validation much shorter and rely on the email service. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: but it is also very small compared to everything that happens in *every* view. In most views, it will load session variables, parse headers, etc. In *most* views it will also make a few queries. Compared to sending an email, validation is really cheap since it is only something that works on the CPU, whereas sending an email also results in work for the network interface, OS calls to wait for a response, etc. Except for numerical analysis, etc. the CPU is not the bottleneck anymore, this is what they call the *Von Neumann bottleneck*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually, comparing this one time validation operation with frequent template preparing, it looks like such an optimization is a little bit off the point. The benefits would make almost no difference on server hardware and cost. Yet, it is still good to save even a drop.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to distinguish. There should be a technical check of validating if the format of an email address is correct or not. That's important to prevent technical hickups or even traffic in the very beginning. It's always great to stop as soon as possible if it's already clear in the beginning that an email is not valid.

The second thing is that you want to check wether an email address is really existent or just technically possible/in the correct format.

So in general: Yes you can validate an email address by just trying to send one validation email to your customers but that very brute forcy and you should avoid it because following technical services may experience problems.

Comment: bjoernffm, I understand your point. But my mind does not consider validation by code as "stopping as early as possible", because what differs in the end is if the mail address is genuine. If the user can trick the validation, which is not hard at all, the server will send activation mail and consume more sources. You might be right about technical hickups but I would rely on smtp structure, software and employees on this part. I am sure that they will avoid invalid adresses and transfers in a better fashion than Django can do.